# Java - About float, long, int

Tags: java, int, long-integer

I have two similar methods but they work different a bit. 
Note:getBytesDownloaded(), getFileSize() return long.

This method return integer value exactly what I expect (eg:51)

```
public int getPercentComplete() throws IOException
    {
        int complete = (int) Math.round(this.getBytesDownloaded()*100 / this.getFileSize());
        return complete;
    }
```

But this method not return any value (even if I change int to long) when run although it's compiled ok:

```
public int getCurrentSpeed() throws IOException
{
    long KBytesDownloaded = this.getBytesDownloaded() / 1024;
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int speed =  (int) Math.round(KBytesDownloaded * 1000 / (currentTime - startTime));
    return speed;
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.myclasses.Downloa
d.getCurrentSpeed()F
        at test$2.run(test.java:87)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

To solve that problem, I change int to float, it works fine (eg:300.0)

```
public float getCurrentSpeed() throws IOException
    {
        long KBytesDownloaded = this.getBytesDownloaded() / 1024;
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float speed =  KBytesDownloaded * 1000 / (currentTime - startTime));
        return speed;
    }
```

Why two similar methods don't return the same type value? Thank you.

Comment: What does "doesn't return any value" means?

Comment: That method cannot possibly not 'return any value' unless it throws an exception, in which case you should have posted the stack trace. Do you mean that it *returns zero?*

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the error:Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.myclasses.Downloa
d.getCurrentSpeed()F
        at test$2.run(test.java:87)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Comment: Blimey. That just means you need to recompile everything. Nothing to do with the code here.

Comment: Java uses integral division. Your whole `(int) Math.round(...)` construct is mostly unnecessary, dividing a `long` by a `long` will give you another `long`. (Although the result will be truncated, not rounded.)

Comment: Also, your second version still uses truncating integer division, it just casts the result to a `float` in the end. If you want more precision, you'll have to use floats from the start. (E.g. start with `double kBytesDownloaded = this.getBytesDownloaded() / 1000.0;`)

Comment: @millimoose: as you said, long/long will return another long. So, can I use this: `long speed =  KBytesDownloaded * 1000 / (currentTime - startTime);`

Comment: @user1780606 If you don't care about the precision loss (in this use case I wouldn't), that will work fine.

Comment: @millimoose: Yes, it compile ok, but still throws error when run.

Comment: @user1780606 If it's still the same error, that's your IDE (Eclipse?) being an idiot.

Comment: I use cmd to compile and run.

Comment: @user1780606 You still got truncation error in your implementation. Neither `1000` nor `(currentTime - startTime)` is an `float` so, their  division will produce truncated `Long` value(**Not Precised**). Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/19022838/1433665

Answer (score 1):

A `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown when a you call a method in a class, but the class does no have that method. This can happen when you already have a compiled program and then change a method declaration in one class without recompiling the classes that depend on it.

In this case your `test` class was compiled to call `float getCurrentSpeed()` in the `Download` class. Then you changed the method return type to `int` without recompiling the `test` class, so that the method needed by `test` no longer exists, hence `NoSuchMethodError`. When you changed the return type back to `float` the problem disappeared.

If you change the return type in `Download`, don't forget to recompile `test`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code with some random int, long, and double variables.

Even though I haven't tried many test cases,

they both seem to be working fine for me.

What do you mean by it doesn't return any value?

==================================================

If it's a no method error, please re-compile and run again.

If that doesn't help then check if you're calling the right functions

Answer (score -1):

[Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28float%29) takes `float` or `double` as argument.

```
KBytesDownloaded * 1000 / (currentTime - startTime)
```

In this expression, `KBytesDownloaded` is `Long`.

The problem is division like `Long/Long` truncates floating point values after decimal.

Make sure to type cast to `float` or `double` to prevent from truncation before rounding the value.

```
 int speed =  Math.round(KBytesDownloaded * (float) 1000 / (currentTime - startTime));
```

Comment: `Math.round()` takes `float` or `double` as argument actually.

Comment: @millimoose Yes, they can but `(Long/Long)` truncates values after decimal.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect So why doesn't your answer mention that as a problem and what it does? As written it implies the parameter type is wrong which isn't the problem.

Comment: @millimoose  Please check my new answer.